# MS Access - summarize data by user and day of week

Tags: ms-access

From Excel, I have to extract data located in an Access database by user and by day of the week, hopefully in the following format:

```
Username  |  Monday  | Tuesday  |  Wednesday  |  Thursday  |  Friday
User1     |  1234    | 4567     |             |            |  0001
User2     |          |          |  7539       |            |
```

The query I am currently using which doesn't give the above-noted format is:

```
SELECT 
    tlkpEmployee.EmployeeLast, 
    tlkpEmployee.EmployeeFirst
    IIf([AbsencePeriod]="Range of dates", IIf("Monday" In (SELECT JourDeSemaine FROM tlkpJulien WHERE SemaineSeTerminant = #2018-08-03# AND LaDate Between tblAbsences.AbsenceDateDébut AND 
    tblAbsences.AbsenceDateFin),[tlkpTypeAbsence].[TypeAbsenceCodeTemps],""),IIf("Monday" IN (SELECT JourDeSemaine FROM tlkpJulien WHERE LaDate = tblAbsences.AbsenceDateDébut),[TypeAbsenceCodeTemps],"")) AS MONDAY, 
    IIf([AbsencePeriod]="Range of dates",IIf("Tuesday" In (SELECT JourDeSemaine FROM tlkpJulien WHERE SemaineSeTerminant = #2018-08-03# AND LaDate Between tblAbsences.AbsenceDateDébut AND 
            tblAbsences.AbsenceDateFin),[tlkpTypeAbsence].[TypeAbsenceCodeTemps],""),IIf("Tuesday" IN (SELECT JourDeSemaine FROM tlkpJulien WHERE LaDate = 
            tblAbsences.AbsenceDateDébut),[TypeAbsenceCodeTemps],"")) AS TUESDAY, IIf([AbsencePeriod]="Range of dates",IIf("Wednesday" In (SELECT JourDeSemaine FROM tlkpJulien WHERE SemaineSeTerminant = #2018-08-03# AND LaDate Between tblAbsences.AbsenceDateDébut AND 
            tblAbsences.AbsenceDateFin),[tlkpTypeAbsence].[TypeAbsenceCodeTemps],""),IIf("Wednesday" IN (SELECT JourDeSemaine FROM tlkpJulien WHERE LaDate = 
            tblAbsences.AbsenceDateDébut),[TypeAbsenceCodeTemps],"")) AS WEDNESDAY, IIf([AbsencePeriod]="Range of dates",IIf("Thursday" In (SELECT JourDeSemaine FROM tlkpJulien WHERE SemaineSeTerminant = #2018-08-03# AND LaDate Between tblAbsences.AbsenceDateDébut AND
            tblAbsences.AbsenceDateFin),[tlkpTypeAbsence].[TypeAbsenceCodeTemps],""),IIf("Thursday" IN (SELECT JourDeSemaine FROM tlkpJulien WHERE LaDate = 
            tblAbsences.AbsenceDateDébut),[TypeAbsenceCodeTemps],"")) AS THURSDAY, IIf([AbsencePeriod]="Range of dates",IIf("Friday" In (SELECT JourDeSemaine FROM tlkpJulien WHERE SemaineSeTerminant = #2018-08-03# AND LaDate Between tblAbsences.AbsenceDateDébut AND 
            tblAbsences.AbsenceDateFin),[tlkpTypeAbsence].[TypeAbsenceCodeTemps],""),IIf("Friday" IN (SELECT JourDeSemaine FROM tlkpJulien WHERE LaDate = 
            tblAbsences.AbsenceDateDébut),[TypeAbsenceCodeTemps],"")) AS FRIDAY FROM (((tlkpAbsenceCatégorie INNER JOIN ((tlkpEmployee INNER JOIN tblAbsences ON tlkpEmployee.EmployeeID = tblAbsences.EmployeeID) INNER JOIN tlkpTypeAbsence ON tblAbsences.TypeAbsenceID = tlkpTypeAbsence.TypeAbsenceID) ON tlkpAbsenceCatégorie.TypeAbsenceCatégorieID = tlkpTypeAbsence.TypeAbsenceCatégorieID) INNER JOIN tlkpChefs ON tlkpEmployee.ChefID = tlkpChefs.ChefID) INNER JOIN tlkpJulien ON (tblAbsences.AbsenceDateDébut = tlkpJulien.LaDate) AND (tblAbsences.AbsenceDateFin = tlkpJulien.LaDate)) INNER JOIN tlkpAbsencePeriod ON tblAbsences.AbsencePeriodID = tlkpAbsencePeriod.AbsencePeriodID WHERE (tlkpChefs.ChefLastName & ", " & tlkpChefs.ChefFirstName) = 'TeamLeader Name';
```

Sorry about the code, I couldn't edit it as I wanted.

The result of the above query is (using the first example) :

```
    Username  |  Monday  | Tuesday  |  Wednesday  |  Thursday  |  Friday
User1     |  1234    |          |             |            |      
User1     |          | 4567     |             |            |      
User1     |          |          |             |            |  0001
User2     |          |          |  7539       |            |
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

The structure is as such:

```
tblAbsences 
AbsenceID   Long Integer data
EmployeeID  Long Integer data
TypeAbsenceID   Long Integer data
AbsenceDateDébut    Date value data
AbsenceDateFin  Date value data

tlkpAbsenceCatégorie
TypeAbsenceCatégorieID  Long Integer data
TypeAbsenceCatégorieNom Text data (variable width)

tlkpAbsencePeriod
AbsencePeriodID Long Integer data
AbsencePeriod   Text data (variable width)

tlkpEmployee
EmployeeID  Long Integer data
EmployeeNom Text data (variable width)
EmployeeFirst   Text data (variable width)
EmployeeLast    Text data (variable width)
EmployeeCiUsager    Text data (variable width)

tlkpTypeAbsence 
TypeAbsenceID   Long Integer data
TypeAbsence Text data (variable width)
TypeAbsenceCodeTemps    Long Integer data
TypeAbsenceCatégorieID  Long Integer data
```

I took @tim-biegeleisen advice to use a cross tab query and have come up with:

```
TRANSFORM Max(tlkpTypeAbsence.TypeAbsenceCodeTemps) AS MaxOfTypeAbsenceCodeTemps
SELECT qryJoinEmployeeAbsences.EmployeeNom
FROM tlkpChefs RIGHT JOIN (tlkpJulien RIGHT JOIN (tlkpTypeAbsence RIGHT JOIN qryJoinEmployeeAbsences ON tlkpTypeAbsence.TypeAbsenceID = 
qryJoinEmployeeAbsences.TypeAbsenceID) ON (tlkpJulien.LaDate = qryJoinEmployeeAbsences.AbsenceDateDébut) AND (tlkpJulien.LaDate = qryJoinEmployeeAbsences.AbsenceDateFin)) ON tlkpChefs.ChefID = qryJoinEmployeeAbsences.ChefID
WHERE (((tlkpJulien.SemaineSeTerminant)=#8/3/2018#) AND ((tlkpChefs.ChefNom)='Gauthier-Hamel, Alexandre'))
GROUP BY qryJoinEmployeeAbsences.EmployeeNom, qryJoinEmployeeAbsences.EmployeeTelephone, qryJoinEmployeeAbsences.EmployeeCiUsager, qryJoinEmployeeAbsences.EmployeeCIDP, tlkpChefs.ChefNom
ORDER BY qryJoinEmployeeAbsences.EmployeeNom
PIVOT tlkpJulien.JourDeSemaine;
```

I originally got an error from Access saying I couldn't LEFT JOIN two tables in the original query that had no data, so I created a separate query named qryJoinEmployeeAbsences to handle the joins.

I am almost there, the query now gives me what I want however I am not getting any results for users that have no absence data.

Comment: That query looks horribly complex for something as simple as the data you want. Please provide input data, so we can create our own query instead of applying a quick fix based on yours.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth, I am aware that my query is likely a lot more complex tha it needs to be, and that would be because I'm fairly new to querying for information and am blindly fumbling about... As for input data, I'm not sure what or how to provide you with that.

Comment: Just provide all the data the query uses to produce the sample result you've shared (the content of _tblAbsences_, _tlkpEmployee_ and _tlkpAbsencePeriod_, including structure).

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth, what I want to appear in the query is as displayed above, however the amounts that appear under the days of the week are what are contained in the tlkpTypeAbsence.TypeAbsenceCodeTemps  and tlkpAbsenceCatégorie.TypeAbsenceCatégorieNom fields. I hope that makes it clear enough...

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple fix to your query, namely just aggregating by the `username`, and taking the `MAX` of the select columns.  Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    tlkpEmployee.username,
    MAX(IIf([AbsencePeriod]="Range of dates", IIf("Monday" In (SELECT JourDeSemaine FROM tlkpJulien WHERE SemaineSeTerminant = #2018-08-03# AND LaDate Between tblAbsences.AbsenceDateDébut AND 
tblAbsences.AbsenceDateFin),[tlkpTypeAbsence].[TypeAbsenceCodeTemps],""),IIf("Monday" IN (SELECT JourDeSemaine FROM tlkpJulien WHERE LaDate = tblAbsences.AbsenceDateDébut),[TypeAbsenceCodeTemps],""))) AS MONDAY
    ... other days here
GROUP BY
    tlkpEmployee.username;
```

I see a discrepancy in the data you showed us.  The query selects the first and last employee name, while your expected output shows the username.  I answered assuming you want the latter.

By the way, the name for this type of query is "pivot query," because we are generating day information in separate columns from an entire table.

Comment: Thanks @tim-biegeleisen, I am now reading up on pivot queries (crosstabs queries I think?). I appreciate your quick response.

Comment: Cross tabs might be a better way to do this, and also you might be able to tidy up your query and make it shorter.  But, at a glance, this is what I would recommend.